# jQuery resize listener to be triggered only change in width

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, width, listener

I need to trigger a function only when the there is a change in width and not in height.
How can I do that without duplicating the function?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var pageWidth = $(window).width();
if(pageWidth > 100){
    $("#content").show();
}
if(pageWidth < 100){
    $("#content").hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think I figured it out

```
var initialWidth = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function() {
  var pageWidth = $(window).width();
  if(pageWidth > 100 && pageWidth !== initialWidth){
    $("#content").show();
    initialWidth = pageWidth;
  }
  if(pageWidth < 100 && pageWidth !== initialWidth){
    $("#content").hide();
    initialWidth = pageWidth;
  }
});
```